# How to add count to array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a counter in a while loop and I want to add every value of that count in an array? Is it possible?
What I tried:

```php
$title_count = 0; 
if(have_posts()){
  while(have_posts()){ 
    $title_count++;
    the_post();
    $max_array = array(); 
    $add_to_array = array_push($max_array, $title_count);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$title_count = 0; 
$counts_array = array();

if(have_posts()){
  while(have_posts()){ 
    $title_count++;
    the_post();
    $counts_array[] = $title_count;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. That worked like a charm for what I wanted to implement.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :**

```
$title_count = 0; 
$counts_array = array();
if(have_posts()){
  while(have_posts()){ 
    the_post();
    array_push($counts_array,$title_count);
    $title_count++;
  }
}
```